# HTML/Javascript search function with AJAX

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, search, html-table

I've created a webpage where I want users to be able to search for a word/term stored in a CSV file, and if that term is found the full line for that line entry will be returned and displayed to the user (ideally in table format, otherwise a textarea will do).

But I need to do this using AJAX, and I also cant use PHP (unfortunately, otherwise I wouldn't be asking this question).

So far I have a table for the form/input/button, and I've also got the code to read the file, but I'm a bit stuck with bringing both together. I know this should be an easy thing to do, but I've spend a lot of time going through tutorials and online questions but havent been able to find anything similar.

If anyone knows of any tutorials that covers this, or can help out with the code below it would be appreciated.

```
  <table>        
     <tr><td>Enter Search Term:
     <input type="text" name="searchword" />
     <input type="button" name="searchbutton" value="Search" onclick="contentDisp();">
     </td></tr>
     <tr><td><textarea id="contentArea" rows="40" cols="60"></textarea></td></tr>
    </table>  //currently using text area but ideally this would be displayed in a table

    <script type="text/javascript">
    function contentDisp()
        {
            $.ajax({
                url : "file.csv",
                success : function (data) {
                    $("#contentArea").html(data); // I THINK SOMETHING NEEDS TO GO IN HERE, WHICH WILL GRAB THE SEARCH TERM ABOVE AND THEN ONLY DISPLAY FILE CONTENTS USING THAT TERM, POSSIBLY 'CONTAIN' */
                }
            });
        }  
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do this strictly via JavaScript by using some strpos and indexOf functions (indexOf is the starting point, while the other will look for the string delimiter(s) ).

it is also possible to do the task with php if you feel comfortable with it, if you're restricted by domain-origin restriction, take a look at JSONP, which stands for JSON with Padding - which basically means that you'll need to wrap the result in a JavaScript function.

good luck.

Comment: Thanks, I saw something on JSON so will go and have another look at that. I know how to do it in PHP, but can't use PHP because of external restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

User Regular Expressions to find your string and to parse the found line in the CSV data.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="text" />
<input type="submit" id="btnsubmit" />
```

Script

```
$(function(){
$('#btnsubmit').on('click', function(){
    var csv = $.ajax('text.csv');
    csv.done(function(data){
        var str = data.split(',');
        var value = $('#text').val();
        $.each(str, function(index, item){
            if(item.match(value)){
                console.log(item) //Output
            };
        })
    })  
})
});
```

CSV

```
Presidency ,President ,Wikipedia Entry,Took office ,Left office ,Party ,Portrait,Thumbnail,Home State
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but unfortunately doesnt work for me. I'm using netbeans and I'm not sure that code works for accessing a file. Also not sure about console.log for the results as I'm not sure how this  displays results. The index also comes up as an error, unused value. Have you tested this? Are you using any additional libraries/plugins?

Comment: console.log will print output in firebug or web developer console. Its the same code you have used. var csv = $.ajax('text.csv'); - fetches the result fron csv. Instead of using success :function() -> I have used csv.done. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ . I have used jquery 1.7.2. Its nothing to do with the IDE (netbeans, dreamweaver etc..).

Answer (score 0):

Why would you use strpos and indexOf when javascript already has built-in functions for matching strings?

http://jsfiddle.net/AWZg8/

Comment: Hi. I was trying to understand what you've posted in the link

Comment: function contentDisp(){                                              
                                                              //jQuery.ajax({                                               //assume this is being called
                //url : "file.csv",
                //success : function (data) {
            //now let's say data gets:
            var data = "one;two;three;four;";
            result = findIn(jQuery("#searchword").val(), data);
            makeList("#contentArea", result);

Comment: I wasnt sure about the way you commented out reading from the csv file. Are you saying that I should call the file there, because there was no other mention of it being referred to anywhere else. Does your example work for csv files with ajax? Or is it just a suggestion?

Comment: Ops. Sorry for the delayed answer; I'm new here and whatever. So the part "jQuery.ajax({   url : "file.csv", success : function (data) {" should not be commented and the code that put's the data in a list would be called in the "success" part of the ajax call.